# scalaquery how to create datetime

Tags: scalaquery

I foundout that scalaquery uses java.sql.date as the date object. But it drops time when I create java.sql.date.

Is there any way that I can use to create **mysql datetime** field in scalaquery?

Comment: Don't have a mysql instance to test against, but have you tried using the implicit conversion between String and mysql datetime?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `java.util.Date` support in ScalaQuery. However, it's possible to enhance ScalaQuery with your own type mappers. For `java.util.Date` such a wrapper could look like this

```
 implicit val JavaUtilDateTypeMapper = MappedTypeMapper.base[java.util.Date, Long]  (_.getTime, new java.util.Date(_))
```

converting the `java.util.Date` into a simple Long. It depends on your database what's the best target, in my case a Long works perfectly.

Comment: +1 nice tip, @Steffan. Pass Long date until you need a Date (i.e. at query time), vs. creating a Date (e.g. from string uri date) and passing to query method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `java.sql.Date`, try using `java.sql.Timestamp`, when declaring the column.

It looks like that yields a better mapping for a column with both date and time elements.